# How to filter Query by nested join in Aqueduct 3?

Tags: postgresql, orm, dart, aqueduct

I have models (simplify):

```dart
class _User {
    int id;

    @Relate(#users)
    Currency currency;
}

class _Currency {
    int id;
    ManagedSet<Price> prices;
    ManagedSet<User> users;
}

class _Price {
    int id;

    @Relate(#prices)
    Currency currency;

    ManagedSet<DefaultPrice> defaultPrices;
}

class _Game {
    int id;
    String code;
}

class _DefaultPrice {
    int id;

    @Relate(#defaultPrices)
    Price price;

    @Relate(#defaultPrices)
    EventTemplate eventTemplate;
}

class _EventTemplate {
    int id;
    ManagedSet<DefaultPrice> defaultPrices;

    @Relate(#eventTemplates)
    Game game;
}
```

And now i want to fetch all event templates for a particular game with included default prices but only with a certain currency.

To solve it i use this code in my controller:

```dart
final String gameCode = request.path.variables['gameCode'];
final User user = request.attachments['user'];

final eventTemplatesQuery = Query<EventTemplate>(database)
  ..where((eventTemplate) => eventTemplate.game.code).equalTo(gameCode);

eventTemplatesQuery.join(set: (eventTemplate) => eventTemplate.defaultPrices)
..where((defaultPrice) => defaultPrice.price.currency.id).equalTo(user.currency.id);
// ..where((defaultPrice) => defaultPrice.price.currency).identifiedBy(user.currency.id); // the same result

final eventTemplates = await eventTemplatesQuery.fetch();
```

I expect that all event templates will be selected, filtered by the game code, after which default prices filtered by currency will be joined. But instead I get an error:

```
[FINE] aqueduct: Query (8ms) SELECT t0.id,t0.code,t0.description,t0.createdAt,t0.updatedAt,t0.game_id,t1.id,t1.createdAt,t1.updatedAt,t1.eventTemplate_id,t1.price_id FROM _EventTemplate t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN _DefaultPrice t1 ON (t0.id=t1.eventTemplate_id AND t3.id = @t1t3_id:int8) LEFT OUTER JOIN _Price t2 ON t1.price_id=t2.id LEFT OUTER JOIN _Currency t3 ON t2.currency_id=t3.id LEFT OUTER JOIN _Game t4 ON t0.game_id=t4.id WHERE t4.code LIKE @t0t4_code:text   {t0t4_code: SM, t1t3_id: 8}
[WARNING] aqueduct: PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t3"   
[SEVERE] aqueduct: POST {{ request.toDebugString() }}  PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t3"
```

Looks like Aqueduct ORM can`t filter with nested JOINs But there is nothing in the [documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/aqueduct/latest/aqueduct/Query/join.html) about limits or restrictions in this case.

```
Aqueduct CLI version: 3.1.0+1
Dart VM version: 2.1.0 (Tue Nov 13 18:22:02 2018 +0100) on "windows_x64"
postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Comment: It looks like unexpected behavior. Details in GH [issue](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/issues/620).